# change the label of a button with class=“btn dropdown-toggle” using javascript or css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I pasted the code below I am beginner in html css and javascript I wanted to change the label of a button without id right now its label is login I wanted to change it to admin is it possible can I use javascript or css? I will really appreciate any advice thank you

```
  </div>
        <div class="nav-no-collapse header-nav"><ul class="nav pull-right">
    <li class=""><a class="btn" href=""><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
    <li class="user-link dropdown">
        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">
             <i class="fa fa-user white"></i> Login //this part I wanted to change it to admin
             <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-menu-title"><span>Account Settings</span></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
    </ul></li></ul></div>
```

I tried using a javascript like this

[image: Javascript I tried]

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question because you are not using punctuation, so it is really hard to read. But if it should be about simply changing the Login to Admin without touching the html, your jQuery should be like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-toggle").text("Admin");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to use jquery..
Then you can use this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fa-user').html('Admin');
    });
```